# Spark case statement if/else

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 data frames, I want to do multiple select queries on the two data frames with a condition. Can I get some help

I want to achieve the following:
`select * from input_file_tmp where input_file_tmp.ckt_id = gsam_temp.CCKT_NO AND gsam_temp.SEV_LVL = '3'`

code:

```
+-----------+--------+-----+----+-------+
|     ckt_id|location|usage|port|machine|
+-----------+--------+-----+----+-------+
|     ckt_id|location|usage|port|machine|
| AXZCSD21DF|     USA|  2GB| 101|   MAC1|
| ABZCSD21DF|     OTH|  4GB| 101|   MAC2|
| AXZCSD21DF|     USA|  6GB| 101|   MAC4|
| BXZCSD21DF|     USA|  7GB| 101|   MAC6|
| CXZCSD21DF|     IND|  2GB| 101|   MAC9|
| AXZCSD21DF|     USA|  1GB| 101|   MAC0|
| AXZCSD22DF|     IND|  9GB| 101|   MAC3|
|ADZZCSD21DF|     USA|  1GB| 101|   MAC4|
| AXZCSD21DF|     USA|  2GB| 101|   MAC5|
| XZDCSD21DF|     OTH|  2GB| 101|   MAC1|
+-----------+--------+-----+----+-------+

+-----------+-------+
|    CCKT_NO|SEV_LVL|
+-----------+-------+
| AXZCSD21DF|      1|
| BXZCSD21DF|      1|
| ABZCSD21DF|      3|
| CXZCSD21DF|      2|
| AXZCSD22DF|      2|
| XZDCSD21DF|      3|
|ADZZCSD21DF|      1|
+-----------+-------+


val x = sql("SELECT * from input_file_tmp,gsam_temp WHERE input_file_tmp.ckt_id = gsam_temp.CCKT_NO AND gsam_temp.SEV_LVL = '3'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter `gsam_temp where sev_lvl = 3` and then do  an inner join on `input_file_tmp.ckt_id = gsam_temp.CCKT_NO`

```
        val df = gsam_temp.join(input_file_tmp,input_file_tmp.ckt_id = gsam_temp.CCKT_NO)
                .filter(col("CCKT_NO")==="3")
```